# Error using Docsify in an Azure Web App

Tags: docsify

I'm trying to run [Docsify](https://docsify.js.org/#/) in an Azure Web App. I'm getting a 404 that looks like there's something I'm missing about configuring the site, perhaps?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html/README.md
```

Has anyone had success using [Docsify](https://docsify.js.org/#/) in an Azure Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  You need to allow IIS to serve markdown files.  You can do that by adding the following to your `web.config` (or adding this *as* your `web.config` if you don't already have one:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".md" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".md" mimeType="text/markdown" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The issue on the Doscify GitHub is [here](https://github.com/QingWei-Li/docsify/issues/405).

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
window.$docsify = {
      homepage: 'readme.md'
}
```

Comment: For me, It works. I used  docsify with docker image.